# 2D array of pointers to char

Tags: c, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

I need to declare an 2D array of pointers to chars -

```
const char* key[4][7] =
{
   {"string1","string2","string3","string4","string5","string6"},
   {"string1","string2","string3","string7"},
   {"string1","string2","string3","string8","string9"},
   {"string1","string2","string3","string10","string11","string12", "string13"}
};
//row is 4 and column is 7 - max number of strings in any array
```

Is this declaration correct? How do I get the number of strings in the each row? And how do I access each element in each row?

Comment: Yes, this is correct, you acces them using `key[row][col]` and there are 7 elems per row in all rows.

Comment: How do I get the number of strings/elements in each row?

Comment: Check if `key[row][col] == NULL` in a loop: `for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)  if (key[row][il] == NULL) count++` ...

Comment: Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Yes, use a more structured language :-) In C this is probably the simplest way, but it depends what you need the data for and how it might need to change..

Answer (score 0):

Below code counts the number of elements in each row and displays it..

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
     int count=0;const char* key[4][7] = 
     {{"string1","string2","string3","string4","string5","string6"},
     {"string1","string2","string3","string7"}, 
     {"string1","string2","string3","string8","string9"},{"string1","string2","string3","string10","string11","string12","string13"}};
     for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
     {
          for(int j=0;j<7;j++)
          {
               if(key[i][j]!=NULL)
               count++;
          }  
        printf("count of element in row %d=%d\n",i+1,count);
        count=0;
     }return 0;
    }
```